# How to push data into object

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to push the {database, id} to the end of the databaseChanges object which will be stored in a state variable as I want to access all of them. However I am getting undefined when I try to set it a new state variable (setDatabaseArr).

Here is my code:

```
const UnitTestsDatabaseView = props => {

  const [databaseArr, setDatabaseArr] = useState('')

  const addToProduction = test => () => {
    const databaseChanges = props.unitTestsData.map(test => {
      return {
        "unit_test_id": test.id,
        "databases": test.databases
      }
    })
      const { databases, id } = test
      console.log(databases, id)

      databaseChanges.push(databases, id)
      setDatabaseArr(databases, id)
      console.log(  setDatabaseArr(databases, id))
      console.log( databaseChanges.push(databases, id))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='Card' style={{marginTop: '40px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
        <div className='TableTopbar UnitTestsGrid'>
            <div>ID</div>
            <div>Name</div>
            <div>Database</div>
            <div />
        </div>

        {props.unitTestsData && props.unitTestsData.map(test =>
          <div key={test.id} className='Table UnitTestsGrid' style={{overflow: 'hidden'}}>
            <div>{test.id}</div>
            <div>{test.unit_test_name}</div>
            <div>{test.databases}
            <div>
                <Checkbox
                  mainColor
                  changeHandler={addToProduction(test)}
                  data={{}}
                  id={test.id}
                />
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          )}
      </div>
    </div>

  )
 }

export default withRouter(UnitTestsDatabaseView)
```

Comment: The `useState` update function takes only a single argument, a value or a function to return the next state. What do you want to be added/updated/saved in local state (`databaseArr`)? Just the current changed object (`{ databases, id }`)? Something else? Are you just logging `databaseChanges`, or rather its new length?

Comment: @bloom bloom Can you tell me the value of unitTestsData ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I review your code, It seems there is a **problem with the implementation on how to push a value to the state**.

I tried to reproduce the problem and try to implement of which I think a solution.

And here is the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

// In order to reproduce the propblem
// Lets that these are the values of the unitTestsData props
// and instead of passing this as value of a props
// I defined it right here.
const unitTestsData = [
  { id: 1, unit_test_name: "Unit I", databases: "test1" },
  { id: 2, unit_test_name: "Unit II", databases: "test2" },
  { id: 3, unit_test_name: "Unit III", databases: "test3" }
];

const UnitTestsDatabaseView = () => {
  const [databaseArr, setDatabaseArr] = useState([]);

  // Maybe you want to push data if the checkbox is checked
  // and pop the data if checkbox is unchecked :: Yes ???
  // This is how you do it.
  const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases }) => {
    setDatabaseArr((previousState) => {
      let newState = [...previousState];
      if (target.checked) {
        newState = [
          ...newState,
          { unit_test_id: newState.length + 1, databases }
        ];
      } else {
        const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id);
        if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1);
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("databaseArr", databaseArr);
  }, [databaseArr]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Card" style={{ marginTop: "40px", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        <div className="TableTopbar UnitTestsGrid">
          <div>ID</div>
          <div>Name</div>
          <div>Database</div>
        </div>

        {unitTestsData.map((test) => {
          const { id, unit_test_name, databases } = test;
          return (
            <div
              key={id}
              className="Table UnitTestsGrid"
              style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
            >
              <div>{id}</div>
              <div>{unit_test_name}</div>
              <div>
                {databases}
                <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    color="secondary"
                    onChange={(e) => addToProduction(e, test)}
                    data={{}}
                    id={id.toString()}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UnitTestsDatabaseView;
```

You may click the codesandbox link to see the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/pushing-value-49f31